# how to log string variable prototype properties in console?

Tags: javascript

I tried below code

```
var carname = "Volvo XC60";
console.dir(carname);
```

This gives nothing but the value. I want to list all prototype functions associated with this variable. This one also is not working.

```
console.dir(carname.prototype);
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you just want to see what methods are available, use the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Found it! How could I missed this?

```
var carname = new String("Volvo XC60");
console.dir(carname);
```

Comment: In Firefox, these function behave quite differently: log only prints out a toString representation, whereas dir prints out a navigable tree. In Chrome, log already prints out a tree -- most of the time. However, Chrome's log still stringifies certain classes of objects, even if they have properties.

Answer (score 1):

What prototype functions do you want to see? For native try this:

```
console.log(new String('carname'));
```

Comment: console.dir(carname); worked! console.log() doesnt log prototypes.

Comment: @Shreejibawa my Google Chrome Dev Tools thinks different

Comment: @Shreejibawa: Only because primitive strings are no objects, and don't *have* prototypes.